# Does the object slide because of the component of gravity that is parallel to the ramp?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, vectors

Does an object slide down a frictionless incline because of  the component of gravity that is parallel to the ramp? I think this is the case, as this component of gravity is in the direction of the object's motion. But when discussing this with another person, he believes that gravity cannot be the driving force because gravity has no component in the horizontal direction. He asked me to provide documentation and peer review, stating that gravity is the driving force. How can I explain this basic scientific common sense?

[image]

$W_n$ and $N$ are balanced, so the components of $W_n$ and $N$ in the horizontal direction are also balanced.  The only thing that is not balanced is $W_t$.  So $W_t$ moves the block down.

Comment: Not clear. Why does the other person believe that a horizontal force is necessary to move the block down the incline? What force does this person believe is responsible for accelerating the block down the incline? If you are asking us how to challenge the other person's explanation then we need to know what that explanation is.

Comment: @sammygerbil https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/214660/176092   He gave a picture of the horizontal component of the lift that caused the glider to glide.  I don't think he is right.  The horizontal component of the lift cannot glide.  I think it is the gravity component in the gliding direction that makes the glider glide.  So I thought about asking this question here.

Comment: That is a different question. You appear to be engaged in a pointless argument. If you want to discuss that answer with the person who posted it you can post a comment under his answer or invite him to a chatroom to discuss what you think is wrong. That person has not asked you to provide documentation and peer review.  Brionius gave you the same explanation as BobD gave you to the same question.

Comment: @sammygerbil Here I am thinking about why the inclined plane and the block move downward.  His explanation was in terms of gliders, not exactly the same as here, but there was an internal connection between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about an object released from rest sliding down an incline. There are two forces acting on a body sliding down a frictionless ramp: gravity and the normal force supplied by the incline that is perpendicular to the incline. Both are important for the object to move down the incline.

**Gravity**: Without gravity, the object would just remain on the incline in the same place you left it, and the normal force would not be present. You can choose to look at the components of gravity parallel and perpendicular to the incline. If you are interested in the acceleration down the incline then the component of gravity parallel to the incline is the only force component that contributes to this acceleration, as it is the only force component that is in this direction.

**Normal force**: Without the normal force, we would predict that the object would accelerate straight downwards (into the incline I suppose). The normal force is perpendicular to the incline, so in terms of our parallel and perpendicular components it only has a component perpendicular to the incline. This component exactly balances the component of gravity that is perpendicular to the incline so that we only have acceleration down the incline.

So, your friend is partially correct. Sure, gravity points down and not horizontally, but a component of gravity is directed down the incline. When taking all forces into consideration, this is the only force component that is left when other components cancel out. However, the normal force is also important, as it allows this cancellation to occur.

Another way to look at the situation as a whole is just in terms of horizontal and vertical components. The acceleration has both a horizontal component due to the normal force and a vertical component due to both gravity and the normal force. This view also helps explain why it takes longer for an object to slide down an incline than it would be just just drop it the same vertical height: the vertical component of the normal force partially cancels the gravitational force.

Comment: The normal component is NOT a reaction force for weight. In fact, it's not a "reaction" at all. The normal force component is an electromagnetically based force due to the interaction of the object and the ramp. But you know that.

Comment: @BillN Can you point to where I specifically call it a reaction force to the weight? The body pushes on the incline, and the incline pushes back on the body. So I called it a reaction force. I wouldn't think a down vote would come from just having a difference in opinion of something so small.

Comment: @BillN I have put a foot note in for you. Although next time a simple clarifying comment would suffice, since nowhere in my answer did I say it is a reaction to the weight

Comment: So is the reaction force moving the object downward or gravity moving the object downward?

Comment: @AaronStevens Because the object has weight, it must move vertically downwards. The ramp prevents the object from moving vertically downwards, so the ramp gives a reaction force to the object.  Right?

Comment: @enbinzheng If you look at it just from a "horizontal and vertical" perspective, the vertical acceleration is affected by both gravity and the normal force. The horizontal acceleration is affected by the normal force. Both forces are required to explain the acceleration of the object.

Comment: @AaronStevens Thanks for adding the footnote. As I implied above, I don't think the use of the word "reaction" is necessary, nor appropriate, cause in modern  language reaction implies a cause. Why use the word reaction at all? It carries a lot of baggage. Or is there a movement trying to rename the normal component? Let's stop using that word. "I don't think it means what [they] think it means." Inigo montoya :)

Comment: @AaronStevens The normal force is balanced, so there is no acceleration in the normal direction, and the tangential force is unbalanced, so there is acceleration in the tangential direction.  The horizontal component of the normal force is balanced by the horizontal component of the normal component of gravity.

Comment: @AaronStevens regarding your point re the horizontal and vertical perspective, I tried to point out the same thing in what was basically the same question by the OP the next  day. At least you were successful since your answer was accepted. I just gave up.

Comment: @AaronStevens Oops just now I see another follow up question by the OP. Caution rabbit hole. Quit while you're ahead!

Comment: @BillN Technically it is a reaction to the object pushing on the incline. But to avoid any other confusion I have just changed it to say "normal force".

Comment: @enbinzheng If you are trying to break your components into components then you are just confusing yourself. If you are talking about horizontal/vertical directions, the object has acceleration in both of these directions. But no matter how you look at it, both forces are required for the object to move down the incline in the way that it does.

Comment: @AaronStevens Although it is troublesome to use my analysis method, I know that the force is balanced in the horizontal direction.  It is also known that the force is unbalanced in the direction of the inclined plane.  So I found the cause of the acceleration of the block.

Comment: @enbinzheng That doesn't make sense. There is acceleration in the horizontal direction, so the force components in the horizontal direction cannot be balanced.

Comment: @AaronStevens As can be seen from the graph in the question, $W_n$ and $N$ are balanced, so the components of $W_n$ and $N$ in the horizontal direction are also balanced.  The only thing that is not balanced is $W_t$.  So $W_t$ moves the block down.

Comment: @BillN At the risk of getting into the foray, I agree with Aaron about the use of the term reaction force. Aren't the forces perpendicular to the incline an action-reaction pair according to Newton's third law? To me the reaction force (the more general term per Newton 3) is called  a "normal" force is simply because this particular reaction happens to be perpendicular to the surface.

Comment: @BobD Objects which contact each other exert forces on each other. Saying one in particular is the reaction to the other, in modern English, is disingenuous because that implies one of them came first. Maybe in Newtonian times it meant something else, or Newton had a different conceptual understanding of the origin of forces. But who is to say that the force of the plane on the block is the reaction? Why not say the force of the block on the plane (outside of our free-body diagram) is the reaction? I prefer to call it what it is -- a contact force (ultimately electromagnetic).

Comment: @BobD Also, the contact force is modeled by 2 components, one perpendicular and one parallel. That parallel component is what we call friction. Friction is part of the contact force. Normal force is part of the contact force. It's usually convenient to our analysis to treat them like that. We often act on an object in a way to cause these components to be time dependent, but the Newton's 3rd Law pair is changing simultaneously, at least in our Newtonian model of analysis.

Comment: @BillN I should have known better to enter the foray into this. But I really don’t like being labeled “disengenuos”. I’ll leave it at that

Comment: @BobD I apologize. I certainly wasn't directing that to you personally. It's simply the whole use of the idea that one force is a reaction to another if one is thinking cause and effect. I have found from my years of teaching that students interpret "reaction" that way. They also greatly mess up Newton's 3rd Law, thinking that the normal component paired with weight. If we, as a group of teachers and professionals, continue to use a term that is commonly misinterpreted when it is easy to use a correct term we are being misleading and should change. What does "reaction force" mean?

Comment: @BobD Be assured, I respect your ability to explain things. Many times I have read a question, then scanned the answers and found that you have said what I was prepared to write. I certainly don't consider you "disengenuous."

Comment: @Bill N thanks Bill. In retrospect it was an over “reaction” on my part. Regards.